# How to know what percentage of visitors to a website don't use javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there an easy way to find out what percentage of visitors to a webpage are not using javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of the more modern analytic programs will do this for you but ...
you can use the  tag and a 1x1 gif and count the hits in the log files.

```
<noscript>
<img src="http://www.mysite.com/assets/images/no_javascript_1x1.gif" alt="" width="1" height="1" border="0" />
</noscript>
```

or for secure pages:

```
<noscript>
  <img src="https://www.mysite.com/assets/images/no_javascript_1x1.gif" alt="no javascript marker" width="1" height="1" border="0" />
</noscript
```

If this was a high use image you could have an issue with proxy caching but suspect there are so few people with no javascript , this will not be an issue.

Mike

Comment: Which free modern analytic programs? I know that google analytics doesn't because it is javascript based. Is there one you have in mind?

Comment: awstats ( log parser not only Javascript based ) 
and Piwik ( Javascript based )

Comment: You will need access to your log files. 

I was thinking of one of these: 

** http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Free_web_analytics_software**

But all they do is something similar - make reference to an image in a noscript tag. 

If its a "one off" you can get a long way with your log files and grep. I have also been known to use Perl for more difficult questions or answers that I need more than once. – MikeyB_Leeds 9 mins ago

Answer (score 9):

If you want to do it yourself try this:

```
<noscript><img src="countNoJS.php" style="display:none" /></noscript>
<script>document.write('<img src="countJS.php" style="display:none" />');</script>
```